# How to sort dictionary with list values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How to sort the below dictionary?

```
dict_val = {"A": ["2", "1"], "B": ["6", "4"]}
```

#### Output:

```
{"A": ["1", "2"], "B": ["4", "6"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that we'd be having `int` in our lists, which in that case,

```
dict_val = {"A": ["2", "1"], "B": ["6", "4"]}

for k,v in dict_val.items():
    dict_val[k].sort(key=int)
```

might be just one way to do so.

Using `sorted` would be another option:

```
for k,v in dict_val.items():
    dict_val[k]=sorted(dict_val[k])
```

#### Output

```
{'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['4', '6']}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to solve it using sorted method ?